# find elements in string

Tags: javascript, regex, find

How can I get a tag along with all the content from a string?

For example there is a string:

```
`
<h2>I'm an extra element</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">I am item!</span>
  <span class="item">I am item!</span>
  <span class="item secondclass">I am item!</span>
</div>
<div>I'm an extra element</div>
`
```

I need to figure out how to get an array of these three elements:

```
<span class="item">I am item!</span>
<span class="item">I am item!</span>
<span class="item secondclass">I am item!</span>
```

Not the content, but the entire element

It would be preferable to do this without Jquery

I'm unfortunately not familiar with regular expressions, so please help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the string into a document with DOMParser, then take the children of `.container` and take each of their `outerHTML`:

```js
const str = `
<h2>I'm an extra element</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span class="item">I am item!</span>
  <span class="item">I am item!</span>
  <span class="item secondclass">I am item!</span>
</div>
<div>I'm an extra element</div>
`;
const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(str, 'text/html');
const spans = Array.from(
  doc.querySelectorAll('.container > *'),
  span => span.outerHTML
);
console.log(spans);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of these three elements 
I am doing it in Java 
and make sure that the string that you are passing for the match i.e(Your first code in your case) all those string must be in a single line or the compiler will consider it as a next line 
   `import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    import java.util.regex.Matcher;

```
public class xyz
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         String[] str = new String[3];
         String str1 = "<h2>I'm an extra element</h2>
                        <div class="container">
                        <span class="item">I am item!</span>
                        <span class="item">I am item!</span>
                        <span class="item secondclass">I am item!</span>
                        </div>
                        <div>I'm an extra element</div>";
         Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<div class=\"container">(.*?)</div>");
         Matcher m = p.matcher();
         while(m.find())
        {
             str = m.group();
             System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
}`
```